# VB.net Hour(Now()) Not Working

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a vb.net program which at a specific time that the user has chosen, the code will excecute. To do this, I need to check every minute to check every minute if the hour and minute the user has entered are matching to the current time (unless there is a better way to do this). I tried to use

```
Dim CurrentHour As Integer = Hour(Now())
```

But the program gives me an error message saying,

> Expression is not an array or method, and cannot have an argument list

I am going to use a Do Loop to check, but of course to see if the two are matching, I need the current Hour and Minute

Comment: You may also wish to consider using the Windows task scheduler; this is what it is designed for.

Comment: You could also use a `System.Timers.Timer` set to fire in the number of milliseconds to the desired time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct.  What you need to watch our for is stuff like this:

```
    Dim Now As Date
    Dim CurrentHour = Hour(Now())
```

Which produces error BC30471: Expression is not an array or a method, and cannot have an argument list.

You see the problem by now perhaps, the Now variable *hides* the Now function.  The compiler now gets confuzzled, it doesn't understand why the parentheses are present.  And correctly complains that Now is not an array and not a method.  It isn't, not anymore.

Other than renaming the variable, you can also solve it by giving a more complete name:

```
    Dim CurrentHour = Hour(DateAndTime.Now())
```

Although that gets to be fairly obscure, using `DateTime.Now` instead is the .NET way instead of the Basic way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [native DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.hour%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) properties:

```
Dim CurrentHour As Integer = Now().Hour
```

If you want to use the Hour method, you may need to fully qualify it to be:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Hour(Now())
```

because Hour is most likely a property or method elsewhere in your application.

Comment: That would answer question of why Hour(Now()) was not working, but a Do loop is not the best way to do things.

Comment: @MontyWild i know i just figured that out and posted a new question asking about the best way

Answer (score 1):

`Dim Inputtime As DateTime
if Inputtime = Date.Now.Hour Then
MsgBox("Success!")
End If`

I wouldn't use a do loop as it will consume all of the memory for the program. I would go with a timer that ticks once every miunute. and have it fire this sub routine.

Comment: how would one go about doing this?

Comment: Making the timer: Inside mainform_load put `CompactTimer.Start() CompactTimer.Interval = 6000` This will makle the timer go off every minute checking to see if the time is correct. Inside timer function: `If (TimeOfDay.Hour & ":" & TimeOfDay.Minute) = Inputtime Then CompactTimer.Stop() MsgBox("Success!") CompactTimer.Start() End If`

Answer (score 0):

[Task Scheduler](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/606876/How-to-create-a-task-in-Windows-Task-Scheduler#) is an option. I rather use `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` then the loop in the bottom of the code, and `GC.Collect` needs to be called again after `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`